# How to add up repetitive values from input in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

i'm kinda new to C.
i am trying to make a shopping cart application program that reads data from a txt file that contains a product and a price, seperated by whitespace.
Then in a new line another product is put and a price(also seperated by whitespace).
then outputs the bill in another "bill.txt" text file.
example:

input taken from file (products.txt):

```
Bread 2.78
cheese 4.59
vegetables 1.99
bread 1.99
Milk 0.56
cheese 2.79
```

output written in another file(bill.txt):

```
bread : 4.77 , 2 products, average-price: 2.38
cheese: 7.38 , 2 products, average-price: 3.69
milk: 0.56 , 1 products, average-price: 0.56
vegetables: 1.99 , 1 products, average-price: 1.99
total : 14.70
```

my main problem is that i am confused about how to add up the sum of the repetitive products like bread from the text file and add them as a quantity instead! The bread is written twice in input but a qty of 2 is written instead.

usually in a language like java i would have used an ArrayList and solved it easily, but since C doesn't have Arraylists, what to do?

here is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count;
struct Product
{
    char productName[30];
    double price;
};

 struct Product p1;

int main()
{
    double total = 0;

    //input file
     FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("products.txt","r");
    //output file
    FILE *fp1 = fopen("bill.txt","w");
    if (fp == NULL || fp1 ==NULL)
    {
        perror("files didn't open");
    }
    printf("this input was written in file:\n");
    while(1)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%s %d",&p1.productName,&p1.price);
        total = total + p1.price;
        fprintf(fp1,"%s:\t%d,  \n",p1.productName,p1.price);
        printf("%s:\t%d,  \n",p1.productName,p1.price);
        if (feof(fp))
        {
            fprintf(fp1,"Total: %d",total);
            break;
        }
}
printf("total: %d", total);
return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know how many products you have? or an upper bound? if not then you must make your product list resizable. If on the other hand you know beforehand exactly the products you have you can make it much simpler.

Comment: 256 is a nice value to pick ;-) Although I see I picked a boring 100 below! For dynamic allocation there are 2 interesting places. The static product name length set to 30 in the example in question. And then the size of list of products. Use static values first, get code working, then as intetresting exercise change to use dynamic allocation for list of products and for product name.

Comment: So you have to do case-insensitive compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to track a list of products and totals, otherwise you would have to iterate the input file multiple times to get total for each product in case the products order is mixed. You could add a total to your product struct, and add an int to track how many things are in list:

```
int itemsInList=0;
struct Product
{
    char productName[30];
    double price;
    int count;
    double total;
};
```

Without worrying about malloc/realloc at first you could use a static list of products.

```
struct Product prodList[100];
```

Write a function which will add an item to your list.
Something like this ...
Pseudocode here for you will have to fix up tolower, strcmp, strcpy bits.
And untested code, apologies if syntax/other errors!

```
addToList(struct Product p) 
{
    // google how to lowercase the product name
    lowname = lowercase(p.productName); // use tolower from ctype.h
    // search your list for product already
    int i;
    int found = 0;
    for(i=0;i<itemsInList;i++)
    {
        if compare(prodList[itemsInList].productName,lowname) // use strcmp
        {  
             // FOUND, add item to total, increment count, set found to true
             prodList[itemsInList].total += p.price;
             prodList[itemsInList].count++;
             found = 1;
             // we could allow loop to continue but for efficiency we end for loop now with break
             break;
        }
    }
    // if not found already add NEW entry to end of list
    if (!found) 
    {
        prodList[itemsInList].productName = lowname;   // use strcpy or strncpy is safer
        // add with correct total and count
        prodList[itemsInList].total = p.price;
        prodList[itemsInList].count = 1;
        // and increment total items in list count
        itemsInList++;
    }
}
```

Google how to lowercase and compare and copy strings:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tolower.3.html
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html

To finish write a function to iterate the list of products and print the bill.

```
void printBill(void) 
{
    // iterate list with for loop and print totals and counts
}
```

Exercise for the future, do it without using global variables to store array and use malloc/realloc to do dynamic memory allocation. Get it working using static array first though.

Answer (score 0):

its correct that you don't have an ArrayList but you still have Arrays you can use

> malloc(), realloc() and calloc()

plus, try to use 2 arrays 1 for the names and 1 for the sums, for example:
in
char** names - you can put the names of the product (lets say the the first one in there is bread)
double* sums - so here in the first one will be the sum of all breads.

malloc, realloc and calloc use RAM memory so be sure to

> free()

them when you done with them.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not a c programmer but I am a dart programmer (dart is a language with c syntax) so :

```
Map shoppingList = {
    "bread" : 2.45,
    "butter" : 2.35,
 };
 
void calculateShoppingList(Map shoppingList) {
   int output = 1;
   
    for (auto const& [String key,Int val] : shoppingList) {
       output = output + val
   }


   return output
}

calculateShoppingList(shoppingList)
```